# Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left( 1-\frac{\lambda}{x} \right)^x = e^{-\lambda}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

Based on the definition of $e: = \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1x \right)^x$, how can we show that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left( 1-\frac{\lambda}{x} \right)^x  = e^{-\lambda}?$$

So far I've tried changing variables, $\eta = \frac{-x}{\lambda}$, so $=\lim_{\eta \to -\infty}\left( \left( 1 + \frac1\eta \right)^\eta \right)^{-\lambda}$. But then we would need to show $\lim_{\eta \to -\infty}\left( 1 + \frac1\eta \right)^\eta =e$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420018/proving-lim-limits-n-to-infty-1-fracxnn-textex?rq=1

Comment: @what'sup The answer on that question (the one without Taylor series) seems to assume $x>0$ (i.e. that as $x\to \infty$, $\frac{x}{\lambda} \to \infty$).

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374747/if-z-n-to-z-then-1z-n-nn-to-ez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:*
$$\left(1+\frac1{\eta}\right)^\eta = \left(\frac1{\left(1+\frac1{-(\eta+1)}\right)^{-(\eta+1)}}\right)^{-\eta/(\eta+1)}$$
and $-(\eta+1) \to +\infty$ as $\eta \to -\infty$.

Comment: Very cool! I wonder why I never did this in Advanced Calculus...

Comment: Is this an example of a more general strategy of some kind? How did you figure out to do this?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\vert}$
When $\lambda = 0$, the result is trivially true: $1 = {\rm e}^{0}$. Let's consider the cases $\lambda \not= 0$:

1. $\large\lambda < 0$
   $$
   \lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1 - {\lambda \over x}\right)^{x}
   =
   \lim_{x\to \infty}\left[%
   \left(1 + {\abs{\lambda} \over x}\right)^{x/\abs{\lambda}}\right]^{\abs{\lambda}}
   =
   \lim_{x\to \infty}\left[%
   \left(1 + {1 \over x}\right)^{x}\,\right]^{\abs{\lambda}}
   =
   {\rm e}^{\abs{\lambda}}
   =
   {\rm e}^{-\lambda}
   $$
2. $\large\lambda > 0$
   $$
   \lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1 - {\lambda \over x}\right)^{x}
   =
   \lim_{x\to \infty}\left[%
   \left(1 - {1 \over x/\lambda}\right)^{-x/\lambda}\right]^{-\lambda}
   =
   \lim_{x\to \infty}\left[%
   \left(1 - {1 \over x}\right)^{-x}\right]^{-\lambda}
   =
   {\rm e}^{-\lambda}
   $$

Otherwise,
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1 - {\lambda \over x}\right)^{x}
=
\lim_{x\to \infty}
\exp\left(\vphantom{\LARGE A^{A}}\,x\ln\left(1 - {\lambda \over x}\right)\right)
=
\lim_{x\to \infty}
\exp\left(\vphantom{\LARGE A^{A}}\,x\left[-{\lambda \over x}\right]\right)
=
{\rm e}^{-\lambda}
$$