# how can I find the supremum??

Tags: analysis

We set $f_n(x)=(1+\frac{x}{n})^n, x \in \mathbb{R}$.Check the uniform convergence of $f_n$ at the intervals $(-\infty,a)$ and $(a,+\infty)$,where $a$ a random real number.

$\lim_{x \to +\infty} {f_n(x)}=e^x$,so $f$ converges pointwise to $e^x$.

To check the uniform converge at $(a,+\infty)$ ,I have to find: $\sup_{x>a} |(1+\frac{x}{n})^n-e^x|$. But..How can I calculate this supremum??

Comment: What is your goal? Your final sentence (in particular, the supremum you wrote) doesn't make sense as written.

Comment: I mean that I want to find the supremum $sup_{x>a} {|f_n(x)-e^x|}$ to check the uniform converge of $f_n$ at $(a,+\infty)$.

Comment: Is that for *fixed* $n$?

Comment: I think so,since the supremum depends from $x$. :-/

Comment: What happens if $x=n$? (Note, the convergence is not uniform on $(a,\infty)$. You don't have to compute the supremum explicitly to show this.)

Comment: @DavidMitra How can I show then that $f$ does not converge uniformly at the interval  $(a,+\infty)$,without calculating the supremum?

Comment: If it did converge uniformly on $(a,\infty)$, there would be an $N$ so that $|f_n(x)-e^x|<1$ for all $n\ge N$ and all $x> a$. But $|f_n(n)-e^n|=e^n-2^n>1$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: You have the difference between an exponential and a polynomial; the former grows faster as $x \to \infty$

Comment: @DavidMitra So,to do it with the way that you said,do we have to suppose that $N=a$ ?

Comment: @dani_s But how can I find like that the supremum?

Comment: No, $a$ is fixed. Given $N$ fixed, choose $n\ge N$, $n>a$, so that with $x=n$ you have $e^n-2^n>1$.

Comment: Possibly a weak duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420018/115115, with lots of ideas.

Comment: @DavidMitra I understand!! And what could I do to show that the function  does not converge at the interval $(-\infty,a)$ ?

Comment: You meant "does not converge uniformly". Take $x=-2n$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I tried it with $x=-2n$ and found that $-1<1-e^{-2n}<1$..

But..which is the contradiction??

Comment: $|f_n(-2n) -e^{-2n}|=|(-1)^n-e^{-2n}|$ is approximately $1$ for large $n$ (since $e^{-2n}$ is small for large $n$).

Comment: @DavidMitra Isn't it $|f_n(-2n)-e^{-2n}|=|(-1)^{-2n}-e^{-2n}|=|1-e^{-2n}|$ ?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry; you're correct. Still, it's around $1$ for large $n$.

Comment: @DavidMitra So,it will be $1<1$,that is a contradiction,right??

Comment: No. To be precise: for any $n$, we have  $|f_n(-2n)-e^{-2n}|=|1-e^{-2n}|\ge 1-{1\over e^2}>0.8$. Let $\epsilon=0.8$. Then there is no $N$ so that $|f_n(x)-e^x|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in(-\infty,a)$ and all $n\ge N$. Thus the convergence is not uniform on $(-\infty,a)$. (The sequence does converge to $e^x$ on $(-\infty,a)$, but not uniformly so.)