# Why does this probability converge towards $1-\frac{1}{e}$?

Tags: probability, derangements

Consider this simple problem:

> If an event has a $1/N$ chance of success, what's the probability of having at least one success after $N$ events?

Basically, what's the chance of getting a $20$ if you roll a D20 $20$ times?

That probability $P(N)$ can be expressed as: $$P(N) = 1 - \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^{N}$$

I found that this [seems to converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%281+-+%28%28x-1%29%2Fx%29%5Ex+%29%3B+%281-1%2Fe%29+from+x+%3D+1+to+25+and+y+%3D+0+to+1) towards $1-\frac{1}{e}$. Why is that?

I'm having trouble understanding what this means. Why does it converge at all? If something has a one in a million chance of happening and you try a million times, shouldn't your chance to succeed be higher that $63\%$? And why this value specifically?

Comment: What do you know about the number $e$?  Have you seen any related limits such as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$?

Comment: Because the sequence $(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$ converges to $\frac{1}{e}$ when $n\to\infty$. This is just a fact.

Comment: Is your question "*why does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ equal $e$?*"  To answer that, we need to know how you define $e$ because otherwise this might just be a direct matter of definition, that $e$ is *defined* that way.  If you already know the answer to the previous part, then is your question "*why does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$ equal $\frac{1}{e}$?*"  then just perform minor algebraic manipulations to get it into the form of the other.  If your question is what $\frac{N-1}{N}$ has to do with these... note $\frac{N-1}{N}=\frac{N}{N}-\frac{1}{N}$

Comment: "*Shouldn't your chance to succeed be [significantly] higher than $63\%$?*"  Do not confuse the probability of at least one occurrence with the expected number of occurrences.  No, the probability should *not* be significantly greater than $63\%$.  The analysis you allude to directly shows this and there is no reason to doubt it.

Comment: In terms of the intuition, note that when $N = 1$, you obviously have a $100\%$ chance of success, for $N=2$, that goes down to $75\%$, for $N=3$, it's $70\%$, and so on, decreasing as $N\to\infty$. With that in mind, are you still surprised that the probability isn't much higher than $63\%$?

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$P(N) = 1 - \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^{N}=1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{N}=1 -\frac1{ \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{-N}}\to 1-\frac1e$$

since

$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} \left(1+\frac1x\right)^x \to e$$

Refer to the related

- [Proving $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty } \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\text{e}^x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420018/505767)

Answer (score 1):

This is more generally related to the fact that the Binomial distribution on $N$ events with success probability $\lambda/N$ converges in distribution to a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda$. In your case, $\lambda=1$, and for Poisson with rate $\lambda$, $1-P_\lambda(X=0)=1-\frac{1}{e^\lambda}=1-1/e$.

A proof can be found [here](https://medium.com/@andrew.chamberlain/deriving-the-poisson-distribution-from-the-binomial-distribution-840cc1668239).